# How to change data reference in realtime database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change this data from Table DraftUsers to Table PublishedUser.
But I have no idea of how I can perform this.
Please Help....

```
{
  "DraftUsers": {
     "CtHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSDDSJ2": "CtHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSDDSJ2",
      "CtHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSFG045": "CtHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSFG045"
      "EKGFUHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSHF78465": "EKGFUHFL9hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSHF78465",
      "FGSGHG3275hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSFG045": "FGSGHG3275hwgfe1oUUVMyqz8BSFG045"
   }
}
```

Comment: Realtime Database does not provide a way to rename a node.  The best you can do is copy the data to a new node and delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    db.child('DraftUsers').once().then((result) async { 
      var yourData = result.value;
      var response = await db.child('PublishedUser').set(yourData);
    });
```

Note: if you want to change specific values, you iterate result.value or get them by ids/keys

Comment: Please accept the answer ! Have a bugless coding :) !!